# Can Apache ProxyPass deny specific patterns?

Tags: proxy, apache

I'm using apache as a reverse proxy, can I do the ProxyPassReverse for all but certain URLs?  For instance here is my config:

```
ProxyPass /myapp http://localhost:8080/myapp
ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://localhost:8080/myapp
```

I want to allow it to forward all requests for http://myserver/myapp to the localhost (which works) except when they try http://myserver/myapp/services/SomeService, then I want it to give back a 404 or something, is that possible with a simply proxy config?

Answer (score 8):

This is definitely a ServerFault question, not StackOverflow.

Regardless, you can negate the ProxyPass for a subdirectory by using an exclamation mark:

```
ProxyPass /myapp/services/SomeService !
```

Then, you can use an Alias directive, if you want HTML to be rendered from a particular directory:

```
Alias /myapp/services/SomeService /var/www/SomeService-files
```